# KOMA-Script TOC modification

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script

By default, KOMA-Script composes headers using sans-serif. I would like to type them in a serif font, so I used:
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\normalfont}

This works, but I would like the label "Contents" in the TOC to also be written in a sans-serif font. How can I do this?

```
\documentclass[mpinclude=true,  version=last, chapterprefix=false,numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\textrm}
\begin{document}
\chapter{chapter 1}
\chapter{chapter 2}
\chapter{chapter 3}
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want all chapter titles with serifs but the title “Contents”, which is also a chapter title, in sans serif, you can change option `sfdefaults` several times:

```latex
\documentclass[mpinclude=true,  version=last,
chapterprefix=false,numbers=noenddot,sfdefaults=false]{scrbook}
\BeforeTOCHead[toc]{\KOMAoptions{sfdefaults=true}}
\AfterTOCHead[toc]{\KOMAoption{sfdefaults}{false}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{chapter 1}
\chapter{chapter 2}
\chapter{chapter 3}
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

[image: heading of chapter 1 with serifs]
[image: table of contents with “Contents” in sans serif]

But I would recommend to use the same font for the heading of the table of contents as for all other chapter headings and therefore either `sfdefaults=false` in the optional argument of `\documentclass` (as shown in egreg's answer) or not. Inconsistency in typography is usually not the very best idea.

Answer (score 5):

1. `\textrm` is wrong and should be `\rmfamily`, if any.
2. In order to have serif titles, there's the specific class option `sfdefaults=false`

```
\documentclass[
  mpinclude=true,
  version=last,
  chapterprefix=false,
  numbers=noenddot,
  sfdefaults=false
]{scrbook}

\begin{document}

\chapter{chapter 1}
\chapter{chapter 2}
\chapter{chapter 3}

\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

"but I would like the label "Contents" in the TOC to also be written in a sans-serif font. How can I do this?"

That would be the standard setting. Do you want to set "Contents" in a serif font as well?

`\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont}` in the preamble would take care of that and of headers on all levels of sectioning.

Comment: Thanks for you answers. I want to change headers to serif font but remain or edit title.of TOC, im this case "Contents", to sans-serif